# PrimeFaces: p:cellEditor is not firing

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

**WHAT I HAVE:**

A basic data-table which, for the sake of simplicity, only shows the amount of items of a certain customer-order.

**PROBLEM:**

When I click the cell, the `<p:inputText>` appears, I am able to enter a number(e.g.: 3). When I press `enter`, the old number (e.g: 42) appears within the `<h:outputText>`. If I click the cell again the edited number (3) appears again. And most importantly the `public void onCellEdit(CellEditEvent event)` method is NOT fired.

**WHAT HAVE I TRIED:**

I have created another basic web-application in which there is only one editable `<p:dataTable>` (as I want it) and in this project the listener fires and I simply don't get what is different. For the sake of simplicity of this question I will not add the code of the other project.

Additionally I have tried to apply the (not) accepted answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22051233/primefaces-pajax-event-celledit-not-firing) question but it did not work either.

**QUESTION:**

Why does the listener not fire ? What might be the reason (or reasons)? Yes, I am a beginner, so any hint would be very welcome.

Thank You !

**xhtml with the table**

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
            xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
            xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
            xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
            template="/templates/template.xhtml">

<ui:define name="metadata"/>
<ui:define name="content">

    <h:form id="lastOrders">

        <p:dataTable id="orders" 
                     var="item"
                     value="#{editController.items}"
                     emptyMessage="Der Kunde hat noch keine Aufträge!" 
                     style="size: 30px"
                     editable="true" 
                     editMode="cell">

            <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{editController.onCellEdit}" update=":mainForm:lastOrders:orders"/>

            <f:facet name="header"> 
                <p:outputPanel>
                    <h:outputText value="#{userController.customer.name}" />
                </p:outputPanel>
                <p:outputPanel>
                    <h:outputText value="#{oldOrdersController.order.date}">
                        <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd.MM.yy" />
                    </h:outputText>
                </p:outputPanel>
            </f:facet>

            <p:column  headerText="Amount">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.amount}"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText id="modelInput" value="#{item.amount}"/>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</ui:define>
```

**This is the EditController**

```
package com.forall.laundry.controller.edit;

import com.forall.laundry.controller.OldOrdersController;
import com.forall.laundry.model.Item;
import com.forall.laundry.service.ItemService;
import com.forall.laundry.service.ProductService;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import org.primefaces.event.CellEditEvent;

    @Named
    @ViewScoped
    public class EditController implements Serializable{

    @EJB
    private ItemService itemService;

    @EJB
    private ProductService productService;

    @Inject
    private OldOrdersController oc;

    private List<Item> items;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        items = itemService.getItemsFrom(oc.getOrder());
    }

    public void onCellEdit(CellEditEvent event) {
        System.out.println("TEST"); // NOT FIRED (i know sysout is not good but no matter what I do here, nothing happens.
    }

    public ItemService getItemService() {
        return itemService;
    }

    public void setItemService(ItemService itemService) {
        this.itemService = itemService;
    }

    public OldOrdersController getOc() {
        return oc;
    }

    public void setOc(OldOrdersController oc) {
        this.oc = oc;
    }

    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    public ProductService getProductService() {
        return productService;
    }

    public void setProductService(ProductService productService) {
        this.productService = productService;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Comment to the solution or workaround:**

In the PrimeFaces [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/edit.xhtml) it is suggested to use `<p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{dtEditView.onCellEdit}" update=":form:msgs" />` but for reasons which are unknown to me the event is not fired and the onCellEdit-method is not called. Therefore I have researched other approaches to fire events and I ended up with the solution below in which I pass the object itself which was changed, rather than the event.
I still don't know why the original code does not work.

Snippet:

```
<p:column headerText="Produkt">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.name}"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <h:inputText id="modelInput" value="#{item.name}">
                            <f:ajax execute="modelInput" event="change" listener="#{editController.onCellEdit(item)}" render=":mainForm:lastOrders:orders"/>
                        </h:inputText>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>
```

Bean-Method:

```
 public void onCellEdit(Item item) {

    //stuff
}
```

Comment: Please add some text what you changed and why that solved it. So others can more easily recognize things for themselves